# Parsing specific values in multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code with a purpose to parse specific information from each of multiple pages. The http of each of the multiple pages is structured and therefore I use this structure to collect all links at the same time for further parsing.

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Links = ["http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com/party-pictures?page=" + str(i) for i in range(2,27)]
```

This command gives me a list of http links. I go further to read in and make soups.

```
Rs = [urllib.urlopen(Link).read() for Link in Links]
soups = [BeautifulSoup(R) for R in Rs]
```

As these make the soups that I desire, I cannot achieve the final goal - parsing structure `<a href= ""> </a>`. For instance,

```
<a href="/party-pictures/2007/something-for-everyone">Something for Everyone</a>
```

I am specifically interested in obtaining things like this: `'/party-pictures/2007/something-for-everyone'`. However, the code below cannot serve this purpose.

```
As = [soup.find_all('a', attr = {"href"}) for soup in soups]
```

Could someone tell me where went wrong? I highly appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am specifically interested in obtaining things like this: '/party-pictures/2007/something-for-everyone'.
>
> The next would be going for regular expression!!

You don't necessarily need to use regular expressions, and, from what I understand, you can filter out the desired links with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
[[a["href"] for a in soup.select('a[href*=party-pictures]')] 
 for soup in soups]
```

This, for example, would give you the list of links having `party-pictures` inside the `href`. `*=` means "contains", [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) is a CSS selector search.

You can also use `find_all()` and apply the [regular expression filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression), for example:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"/party-pictures/2007/")
[[a["href"] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=pattern)] 
 for soup in soups]
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks so powerful and I am intrigued to learn more about it. As I run this code, however, I obtained `  File "graph.py", line 16, in <module>
    parties = [[a["href"] for a in soup.select('a[href*=party-piecutre')] for soup in soups]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1426, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "a[href*=party-piecutre"`

Comment: @Hsun-YiHsieh ah, sorry, missed the closing `]`, fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
As = [soup.find_all(href=True) for soup in soups]
```

This should give you all href tags

If you only want hrefs with name 'a', then the following would work :

```
As = [soup.find_all('a',href=True) for soup in soups]
```

Comment: Thank you. The next would be going for regular expression!!